# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MsalGuard -> Router]

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, ionic4, angular-router, azure-ad-msal

I've built a webapp using ionic. I'm trying to import the MSALModule into my app. According to the tutorials etc I've found online, you have to add following to app module :

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: OAuthSettings.appId
    }),
```

currently its giving me the following error when I try to go to the page where it is used.

```
We have a generic Error:  Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MsalGuard -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MsalGuard -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MsalGuard -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MsalGuard -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10847)
    at _createClass (core.js:10888)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10858)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4733)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

I don't have the routing module imported cos i'm not using angular (or ionic) routing in the app. Is there a way to get rid of this error without using routing? i.e. can I use MSAL without setting up routing in my app?

Comment: Can you add 'Router' to services array and try?

Comment: @ppgowda4 what do you mean?

Comment: MSAL needs routing module. you need to import that

Comment: @ppgowda4 I was trying to use msal because I tried getting the access token by sending get request to the authorize endpoint (implicit flow for graph api) but its returning an invalid token. Would you know why this is?

Comment: You can check this issue if it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769462/how-do-i-configure-msal-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

I see you have the import statement...did you add to the Providers section:

{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true }

My understanding is it is not absolutely necessary, as long as you have a custom provider that you have developed. But, if that doesn't exist, you  need to have this in your providers section.