# One or more scopes are not compatible with each other, Login with Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bing-api

Actually I’m trying to get access token with the scope of `User.Read` and `https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage`, but problem is that token is not generating its return that compatibility issue.

Response is:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'User.Read https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage' are not compatible with each other.\r\nTrace ID: 39f45ba8-5264-4a49-8620-992312ec6f00\r\nCorrelation ID: aa6c6629-0503-44ef-9fd6-0ffeabdf8dd3\r\nTimestamp: 2023-05-15 09:23:49Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70011
    ],
    "timestamp": "2023-05-15 09:23:49Z",
    "trace_id": "39f45ba8-5264-4a49-8620-992312ec6f00",
    "correlation_id": "aa6c6629-0503-44ef-9fd6-0ffeabdf8dd3"
}
```

Comment: I think that you will need two different tokens because you want to use two different API - Graph API and Bing Ads Api

Comment: For that user will see 2 popup windows? One for user info and other for ads api access ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get access token on the behalf of the user:

```
Authorization request

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
&state=12345
```

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#authorization-request.

for custom api's and own api's check out this, it has similar question:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874064/access-token-for-both-microsoft-graph-and-custom-api#:~:text=The%20steps%20are%20pretty%20straightforward%3A%20Update%20your%20AAD,token%20that%20can%20be%20used%20with%20Microsoft%20Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874064/access-token-for-both-microsoft-graph-and-custom-api#:%7E:text=The%20steps%20are%20pretty%20straightforward%3A%20Update%20your%20AAD,token%20that%20can%20be%20used%20with%20Microsoft%20Graph).